# Format Currency using Jquery (Remove trailing zeroes after decimal place)?

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery script that formats my numbers in a `div` as currency.

```
So 2000 becomes £2,000.00
```

My question is, how can I remove the trailing zeroes after the decimal point? So that my currency looks like:

`£2,000`

Here is my code:

```
<script>
/*Works only with Chrome 
Inspired by Erik Deiner's concept :
http://dribbble.com/shots/435827-Concept-for-budget-price-slider
*/
$('#rate4').on("input", function() {
  $('#rate_out4').val('£' + parseFloat(this.value, 10).toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,").toString());
}).trigger("change");
</script>
```

Please can someone show me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Is it necessary you to use parseFloat method or you can use parseInt as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sure the output would have the format of `.xx` you can simply use [`.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring): `.substring(0,a.length-3)`. Alternatively, you could also use [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace): `.replace(/\.\d*/,'')`. [Test regex](https://regex101.com/r/W34lBV/1)

```js
var a= "£2,000.00";
console.log(a, a.substring(0,a.length-3), a.replace(/\.\d*/,''));
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by changing my code slightly and using this line:

```
  $('#rate_out4').val('£' + parseFloat(this.value, 10).toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,").toString().slice(0,-3));
```

Answer (score 0):

I am just curious that you really need parseFloat method, if your calculations or display values are not in decimals. Then simply you can use parseInt and don't have to worry about string formats.

```
         <script>
/*Works only with Chrome 
 Inspired by Erik Deiner's concept :
 http://dribbble.com/shots/435827-Concept-for-budget-price-slider
 */
$('#rate4').on("input", function() {
  $('#rate_out4').val('£' + parseInt(this.value, 10).replace(/(\d)(?= 
  (\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,").toString());
}).trigger("change");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat) object like this:

```js
var number = 2000;

console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-UK', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'GBP',
  maximumSignificantDigits: 21
}).format(number));
```